# why isn't my html form and button centered after using display: inline;

Tags: html, css

The form and button are on the left hand side of the screen, how do I get them in the center?
If I don't include "display: inline;" the form is centered in the middle of the page but as soon as I include it the form is on the left hand side of the screen.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rounded">
<FORM name="myForm" method="POST" action=""; onsubmit="validate();">
<input type="text" value="Start time">  
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick="validate1();" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
rounded{
text-align:center;
align:center;
}

form {
margin:0 auto; 
text-align:center;
align:center;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: There is no `align` property in CSS. It is invalid and does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9fpZ/) and css.

```
.rounded{
text-align:center;
}

form {
margin:0 auto; 
text-align:center;
display: inline-block;
}
```

You also need to keep button within form

```
<div class="rounded">
    <FORM name="myForm" method="POST" action=""; onsubmit="validate();">
        <input type="text" value="Start time">  
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
        <button type="submit" onclick="validate1();" >Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The inline-block did the trick and thanks for cleaning up the code a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

`rounded` matches `<rounded>` elements, but your container is a `<div>` with `class="rounded"`.

Use `.rounded` to match elements that are members of the *rounded class*.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width and margin to the css of the rounded box like this:

```
.rounded {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    /* align: center; - Remove this */
}
```

This worked on my test of your code.

Comment: And remember to do what @Quentin said and add a '.' to the beginning of 'rounded'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.rounded
{
    text-align:center;
    align:center;
}
```